# Angular 2 Accents not showing

Tags: html, angular, display

I set `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the **index.html** 
I set each affected html file in \File\File Encoding to UTF-8 and save.
Instead of following characters **á Á é É í Í ó Ó ö Ö ú Ú ü Ü ű Ű** in the distributed files (**main.bundle.js** and **main.bundle.js.map**) I found the following **Ã¡ Ã Ã© Ã‰ Ã­ Ã Ã³ Ã“ Ã¶ Ã– Ãº Ãš Ã¼ Ãœ Å± Å°** Of course didn't appear the expected result.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Klw</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**welcome.component.html**

```
<div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h4 id="welcome_msg" class="text-center"><p class="text-primary">Welcome to á Á é É í Í ó Ó ö Ö ú Ú ü Ü ű Ű 's webpage!</p></h4>
</div>
```

I don't know what did I wrong.
Locally it works well. (ng serve)
The displayed result is on the server:
[image: Here is the result]

Comment: please add your file/files

Comment: Provide your code

Comment: Here is my welcome.component.html <div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h4 id="welcome_msg" class="text-center"><p class="text-primary">Welcome to á Á é É í Í ó Ó ö Ö ú Ú ü Ü ű Ű 's webpage!</p></h4></div>

Comment: Here is my index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Klw</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I also tried to save the source (html) file in UTF-8 format with Notepad++ and TextPad.

Comment: I using Bootstrap 4

Comment: Have you checked HTTP response headers (content-type) when it's deployed on your server? The headers have priority over HTML meta tag.

Comment: I see the following: Content-Type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2 
Why I not see UTF-8? 
I saved the index.html too in UTF-8 format with Sublime Text 3

Comment: I checked, my file welcome.component.html is really in UTF-8 format because where the character 'á' begins in byte I found there two hex bytes 0xC3 and 0xA1 which is in UTF-8 the character 'á', here is the reference of it: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e1/index.htm